# JavaScript Date() malfunctioning between timezones?

Tags: javascript, date

I have a website where dates are sent to and from the server using JSON.stringify(). If the client writes a comment it is sent to the server with a date string, which looks like this

```
"2013-09-21T04:00:00.000Z"
```

When the server gets the string I create a new date from the string

```
var server_date = new Date("2013-09-21T04:00:00.000Z");
```

This date variable is stored in a MongoDB. But when the client reloads the page the date string the client receives looks like

```
"2013-09-21T00:00:00.000Z"
```

And when I make a new date from this string on the client

```
var client_date = new Date("2013-09-21T00:00:00.000Z");
```

the date object is incorrect. Somehow when I set the client_date the date is set to 9/20/2013 rather than 9/21/2013. When running the server on my local machine this was never a problem. Currently the server is running on AWS so I'm assuming that this is somehow messing with the dates? But I don't understand how the client_date variable is set one day before the date specified in the string, regardless of the hours-min-seconds. How can I format my dates to fix this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Z` means Universal Time Coordinated (UTC) or Greenwich Mean Time (GMT). Therefore, when it's `2013-09-21T00:00:00.000Z` in Greenwich it's still the 20th of September west all the way to where your Client is.

Comment: Thanks! To correct the problem I'm just stripping the time aspect of the date and creating a new date with the day, month and year. Is there some way I can avoid the problem?

Comment: Why does your date String look like `2013-09-21T00:00:00.000Z`? Are you using `new Date().toJSON()`? Anyways, that probably is the Client's time, if they are in a different timezone. If you want a consistent time, and you are using PHP then use `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles')` with the correct timezone and do something like `$dt = date('D M Y h:i:s').' GMT-0700 (Pacific Standard Time)';` to make it look like the JavaScript output. Of course, use the correct timezone.